# How to handle the on change & enter key press in p:inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Below example we tried, but there is no luck

On change (Tab or mouse click) this code is working fine. When Enter key is pressed it is executing two times.

Please help me to fix the issue.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRemCo"
                 action="#{someBean.action}"
                 process="@this myInput"
                 update="myInputMessage"/>

<p:inputText id="myInput"
             value="#{someBean.value}"
             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) { myRemCo(); return false; }"
                     onchange="myRemCo();"/>
```

Comment: What if you remove the `myRemCo()` call from `onkeypress`?

Comment: Hi, I corrected your tagging and title. and what ius executed twice? If it is the `myRemco()` it is not remoteCommand related.

Comment: Enter will submit the form by default.. if you don't want that to happen, prevent it (you will find many questions on that subject here).